sumar un dia a fecha fullcalendar
Hola a todos uso fullcalendar para mostrar en el calendario unos eventos recuperados en una base de datos pero en un calendario de esos me gustaría que resaltara el día siguiente al actual.. esta parte del código que usa fullcalendar es donde veo donde se usa para capturar la fecha actual pero no he podido sumarle un día a esa variable.. he jugado con los +1 en el día que aparece allí pero no me resulta, sigue apareciendo el día actual resaltado en le calendario.
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var date = new Date();
       date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + 1); //sumo 1 día
       
        const yyyy = date.getUTCFullYear();
   const mm = (date.getUTCMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
   const dd = date.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')
       
       
      // var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
       //var mm = (date.getMonth()+1).toString().length == 1 ? "0"+(date.getMonth()+1).toString() : (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
       //var dd  = (date.getDate()).toString().length == 1 ? "0"+(date.getDate()).toString() : (date.getDate()).toString(); 
       
       

        
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                language: 'es',
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',

            },
            defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            defaultDate: yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd,
            
            // OCULTAMOS LOS DIAS ANTES Y DESPUES DE CADA MES------
            showNonCurrentDates: false,
            editable: false,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end, fechainicial) {                
                $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
                $('#ModalAdd #fechainicial').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
            },
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.bind('click', function() {
                    $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
                    $('#ModalEdit #id_contrato').val(event.id_contrato);
                    $('#ModalEdit #cedula').val(event.cedula);
                    $('#ModalEdit #numero').val(event.numero);
                    $('#ModalEdit #nombre').val(event.title);
                    $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
                    $('#ModalEdit #cargo').val(event.cargo);
                    $('#ModalEdit #municipio').val(event.municipio);
                    $('#ModalEdit #imagen').val(event.imagen);
                    //$('#ModalEdit #periodojunto').val(event.periodojunto);
                    $('#ModalEdit #start').val(event.start2);
                    $('#ModalEdit #end').val(event.end2);
                    $('#ModalEdit #fechainicial').val(event.fechainicial2);
                    $('#ModalEdit #duracion').val(event.duracion);
                    $("#imagen").attr("src", "https://serviaseo.net.co/reporteoficinas/fotos/foto-"+event.imagen);
                    $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
                    });
                    
            },
            eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

                edit(event);

            },
            eventResize: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

                edit(event);

            },
            events: [
            <?php foreach($events as $event): 
                    
                $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
                $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
                $fechainicial = explode(" ", $event['fechainicial']);
                
                //--------------------------
                if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $start = $start[0];
                }else{
                    $start = $event['start'];
                }
                //---------------------------------
                if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $end = $end[0];
                }else{
                    $end = $event['end'];
                }
                //---------------------------------
                if($fechainicial[1] == '00:00:00'){
                    $fechainicial = $fechainicial[0];
                }else{
                    $fechainicial = $event['fechainicial'];
                }
                                
                
            ?>
                {
                    id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
                    numero: '<?php echo strtoupper($event['numero']); ?>',
                    title: '<?php echo eliminar_acentos(strtoupper($event['title'])); ?>',  
                    cargo: '<?php echo strtoupper($event['cargo']); ?>',
                    municipio: '<?php echo strtoupper($event['municipio']); ?>',
                    start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
                    start2: '<?php echo strtoupper(fechaCastellano($start)); ?>',
                    end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
                    end2: '<?php echo strtoupper(fechaCastellano ($end)); ?>',  
                    fechainicial: '<?php echo $fechainicial; ?>',
                    fechainicial2: '<?php echo strtoupper(fechaCastellano($fechainicial)); ?>', 
                    color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
                    duracion: '<?php echo strtoupper($event['duracion']); ?>',
                    imagen: '<?php echo $event['id_contrato']; ?>',
                    id_contrato: '<?php echo $event['id_contrato']; ?>',
                    cedula: '<?php echo number_format($event['id_contrato'], 0, ',', '.'); ?>',
                },
    
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            ]
        });
        function edit(event){
            start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            if(event.end){
                end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            }else{
                end = start;
            }
            
            id = id;
            color = color;
            
            $.ajax({
             url: 'editEventDate.php',
             type: "POST",
             data: {id:id, color:color},
             success: function(rep) {
                    if(rep == 'OK'){
                        alert('Evento se ha guardado correctamente');
                    }else{
                        alert('No se pudo guardar. Inténtalo de nuevo.'); 
                    }
                }
            });
        }
//--------------------------------
$("#botonir" ).click(function() {
    let idww = document.getElementById("id").value;
    let cedulaww = document.getElementById("cedula").value; 
    cedulaww = cedulaww.replace(/\./g,'')
window.open("generarrecorda.php?id="+idww+"&identificacion="+cedulaww, "Generar Documento", "width=804, height=1028")
}); 
    });
</script>


defaultDate se ha renombrado en la versión 4 a initialDate, en ambos casos lo que hace fullCalendar es mostrar la fecha seteada en ese campo, pero no te resaltará la fecha. Porque la fecha resaltada es now
Es decir, son conceptos diferentes.

defaultDate y initialDate Indica que fecha inicial se debe mostrar, eso no cambia que "hoy es hoy"
now Le indica al calendario que la fecha de "hoy" es otra

Por otro lado, ojo con las funciones de fecha de javascript. Tienen un problema del offset dado por el UTC. Por ejemplo:


const date = new Date("2024-12-31");

console.log(date.getDate())
console.log(date.getUTCDate())



Salvo que estes configurado en UTC=0, en el ejemplo anterior deberías ver 2 días distintos para la misma fecha. A modo de recomendación genérica, deberías preferir las funciones que llevar un UTC en su nombre
Demo:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   const date = new Date();
   date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + 1); //sumo 1 día

   const yyyy = date.getUTCFullYear();
   const mm = (date.getUTCMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
   const dd = date.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')


  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    now: `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}` //Cambia el día actual
  });
  calendar.render();
});
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.15/index.global.min.js'></script>

<div id='calendar'></div>




Ejemplo con la versión 3.4


$(document).ready(function() {

  const date = new Date();
  date.setUTCDate(date.getUTCDate() + 1); //sumo 1 día

  const yyyy = date.getUTCFullYear();
  const mm = (date.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
  const dd = date.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')


  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    now: `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`, //Cambia el día actual


    //El resto de configuraciones

    header: {
      language: 'es',
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',

    },
    defaultView: 'basicWeek',

    // OCULTAMOS LOS DIAS ANTES Y DESPUES DE CADA MES------
    showNonCurrentDates: false,
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id='calendar'></div>




mil gracias por responder.. debo tener una versión vieja del full calendar por que mi código no me sale así.. he hecho adecuaciones a mi código mirando el ejemplo que poner pero no me resulta

@Eduardo de tu código original, solo cambia defaultDate: yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd, por now: yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd, y ve si funciona, en caso contrario debes agregar la versión que estas utilizando a tu pregunta

hola ya le adicione esa linea y no funciona, ya edite el código con el código que usa mi versión.. mil gracias

@Eduardo Pasa que en tu código no logro ver que versión usas. Debes abrir el archivo JS de fullcalendar y seguramente arriba aparece

sii mil gracias por responder.. aparece esto en el archivo js /*!

FullCalendar v3.4.0
Docs & License: https://fullcalendar.io/
(c) 2017 Adam Shaw
*/


@Eduardo Al final de la respuesta he agregado un ejemplo con la versión 3.4,

Funciono perfecto.. de mil maravillas!!
